# what library should I #include when using switch-case statement

Tags: arduino-uno

I receive an error code of: `'switch' was not declared in this scope`

The code is correct so I assume that the necessary library was not included.

Please tell me the correct `#include` to use.

```c
swith(pwm){
  case 0:   Serial.print(pwm); Serial.print("   ");_delay_ms(2000);
            break;
  case 31:  Serial.print(pwm); Serial.print("   ");_delay_ms(100);
            break;
  case 63:  Serial.print(pwm); Serial.print("   ");_delay_ms(100);
            break;
  case 95:  Serial.print(pwm); Serial.print("   ");_delay_ms(100);
            break;
  case 127:  Serial.print(pwm); Serial.print("   ");_delay_ms(100);
            break;
  case 159:  Serial.print(pwm); Serial.print("   ");_delay_ms(100);
            break;
  case 191:  Serial.print(pwm); Serial.print("   ");_delay_ms(100);
            break;
  case 124:  Serial.print(pwm); Serial.print("   ");_delay_ms(100);
            break;
  case 156:  Serial.print(pwm); Serial.print("   ");_delay_ms(100);
            break;
  case 188:  Serial.print(pwm); Serial.print("   ");_delay_ms(100);
            break;
  case 220:  Serial.print(pwm); Serial.print("   ");_delay_ms(100);
            break;
  case 252:  Serial.print(pwm); Serial.print("   ");_delay_ms(100);
            break;
  default:  break;
}
```

Comment: spelling error.  switch not swith

Comment: `I receive an error code of: 'switch' was not declared in this scope` ... no, you don't get that error ... look at the message again ... next time copy and paste the message ... you cannot trust yourself to correctly type in what it says

Answer (score 3):

It seems you have a syntax error: write `switch` instead of `swith`.